# Django REST, Accessing methods of the selected object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this part of my code fills the queryset with [category_object].subcats.all(). let subcats be a method of category object:

serializer:

```
class CatSrlz(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('id', 'label', )
```

View:

```
class CatsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
serializer_class = CatSrlz

def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # return Response({'res': self.kwargs})
    queryset = Category.objects.get(pk=str(self.kwargs['pk'])).subCats.all()
    dt = CatSrlz(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(dt.data)
```

and url:

```
router.register(r'cats', views.CatsViewSet)
```

it works but i'm pretty sure that there must be a more correct way of doing so
Is there one?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving a single object, you can use the get_object method in your view, which look like this in DRF without modifications :

```
def get_object(self):
    """
    Returns the object the view is displaying.

    You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
    queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
    keyword arguments in the url conf.
    """
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    # Perform the lookup filtering.
    lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
        'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
        'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
        'attribute on the view correctly.' %
        (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
    )

    filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

    # May raise a permission denied
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

    return obj
```

So you could adapt the part where you get your object :

```
filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
```

and add your subcat logic there.

By the way, I don't get why you are using

```
dt = CatSrlz(queryset, many=True)
```

Shouldn't "retrieve" return a single object?

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. and yes i think so, that was because of a wrong approach! corrected it. thanks for your mention